# SQLAlchemy: Simple ordering across many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm pretty new to SQLAlchemy, and am trying to figure out how to set up the most straightforward `order_by` on a many-to-many relationship with an Association Object. I saw a few questions here about ordering by the count, but not this more basic one.

Assume these tables (simplified from the actual ones):

```
class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'event'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))
    date = db.Column(db.Date)

    guests = db.relationship('Guest_Event', back_populates='event')

class Guest(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'guest'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(256))

    events = db.relationship('Guest_Event', back_populates='guest')

class Guest_Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'guest_event'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    guest_id = db.Column('guest_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('guest.id'))
    event_id = db.Column('event_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'))
    guest = db.relationship('Guest', back_populates='events')
    event = db.relationship('Event', back_populates='guests')
```

All I want to do is to have something like:

```
event = Event.query.get(id)
# Then in a Jinja2 template:
<p>The following people were at this event:</p>
{% for guest_event in event.guests %}
  {{ guest_event.guest.name }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

where this list is ordered by guest.name, or similarly

```
guest = Guest.query.get(id)
# Jinja2:
<p>{{ guest.name }} was at these events:</p>
{% for guest_event in guest.events %}
    {{ guest_event.event.date }}: {{ guest_event.event.description }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

where this is ordered by event.date, possibly descending.

I've tried putting `order_by='Guest.name'` in the Guest_Event class or the Event class, both of which throw an SQL error "Unknown column guest.name in order clause", not surprisingly since this query is only operating on the association table. But I don't know what else to do.

Ultimately I'd like to make an Association Proxy, since I'd like to just be able to do `for guest in event.guests` and then `guest.name` directly, instead of bothering with the association class.

Also: how would you change this query on the fly? If, for example, I wanted to order events by event.date ascending in one case, descending in another, or by other things that I'm not showing in this simplified example.

Comment: In short, use `guest = db.relationship('Guest', back_populates='events', lazy='joined', order_by='Guest.name')` in `Guest_Event` association object model.

Answer (score 2):

Either:

1) Construct a new query

```
guests = Guest.query.\
    join(Guest_Event).\
    join(Event).\
    filter(Event.id == event.id).\
    order_by(asc(Guest.name))
```

and loop through those results, or

2) Use Python to do the sorting:

```
 for guest_event in sorted(event.guests, key=lambda x: x.name):
```

Comment: I'll add that, if you use a Table instead of a Model as your association object, you should be able to get rid of the join through `Guest_Event`. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: Thanks. This does indeed work, though I had hoped there would be a less messy solution.

I can't use a Table as the association object; this is a simplified example, and in the real `Guest_Event` table I have other columns that I use in other contexts.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda the price you pay for having non-linking columns in your relationship table and needing to change the ordering on the fly.

If you look at the linked duplicate question, there is an example for hard-coding the order by in the relationship--but this may only work for explicit joins (the documentation is vague).